# Find max(value) and min(value) from one column and pull records from various other fields on same row

Tags: sql, oracle

Using SQL through Oracle

Here is a mock of how my data is formatted

```
Unique_id    Search_Date    Value
    1               01-Jan-2015      3
    1               02-Jan-2015     -5
    1               03-Jan-2015      8
    2               01-Jan-2015     17
    2               02-Jan-2015     20
    2               03-Jan-2015    -50
    3               01-Jan-2015      4
    3               02-Jan-2015     24
    3               03-Jan-2015    -12
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRIkB.png)

I need to pull max(value), min(value) PER unique_id and I need to pull the exact search_date of those aggregates.

Any ideas? I can pull the max and min values per hotel_id, but I can't pull in the search_date value.

Comment: Please note that sample data in image form is generally discouraged here in SO. It is always preferable to provide sample data as formatted text.

Comment: Which date should be shown in a case when there are two records with the same minimum value, but two different dates ?

Comment: Good point @Kordirko. Actually, in the final version of my query I won't necessarily have a preference. I'm just trying to locate any date by unique_id where these max and min values occur to run an analysis on another table, but definitely something to consider in the future

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I SELECT the first row with MAX(Column value)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375327/how-can-i-select-the-first-row-with-maxcolumn-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Oracle you can do this with aggregation:

```
select unique_id, max(value), min(value),
       max(search_date) keep (dense_rank first order by value asc) as date_min, 
       max(search_date) keep (dense_rank first order by value desc) as date_max
from t
group by unique_id;
```

Comment: DUUUUUUUUUUUUUDDEEEEEE!!! You're the man! I've been tearing my hair about over this for the past 24 hours lol. I'm still relatively new at coding so it's frustrating to hit road blocks where the answer are to using functions I didn't know existed.

Comment: The `keep` functionality in Oracle is quite useful, but not as well-known as the other analytic and aggregation functions.